# SQL like concat doesn't select specific value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables where in one field I need to search for a value in another row, the row is a concatenated string. Something like this:

Table1:

```
|id|Name |Itemsid  |
|1 |John |1        |
|2 |Hans |4, 22, 23|
|3 |Chris|2, 4,    |
|4 |Jorn |4, 22, 23|
|5 |Claus|1, 4, 23 |
|6 |Marco|22, 4    |
```

Table2:

```
|id |item       |
|1  |Mobile     |
|2  |Creditcard |
|3  |Wallet     |
|4  |Car        |
|22 |House      |
|23 |Boat       |
```

Expected result

```
4|Jorn|Car
4|Jorn|House
4|Jorn|Boat
```

I tried

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.itemsid LIKE CONCAT ('%', Table2.id, '%') 
WHERE Table1.name = Jorn
```

Resulting in

```
4|Jorn|Car
4|Jorn|Creditcard
4|Jorn|Wallet
4|Jorn|House
4|Jorn|Boat
```

Therefore I tried a `regexp` so the inner join would be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.itemsid REGEXP CONCAT ('(,|\s|^)', Table2.id, '(,|\s|$)') 
WHERE Table1.name = Jorn
```

Resulting in

```
4|Jorn|Car
```

So the problem using `like concat`, is that it doesn't select the specific value but in also select 2 if the id is 22.

Problem with `regexp` is that it only select the first id, and don't go through the list.

So I am looking for a query that will give me the expected result instead.

Comment: Your Database Design is bad. You need move in other table the Itemsid Field, and after link the table 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a delimiter problem.  You can solve this with:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN
     Table2
     ON concat(', ', Table1.itemsid, ', ') LIKE CONCAT ('%, ', Table2.id, ', %') 
WHERE Table1.name = 'Jorn';
```

However, you should really use a junction table instead.  Storing lists of integers in strings is a bad idea.  SQL has a great construct for storing lists.  It is called a table, not a string.

Comment: Thanks.. I know (now) I should do the junction table after i read about it, thanks for pointing it out!